# What is the delegate method to catch the transition of images in SDWebImage component?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, sdwebimage

I am writing the following code that uses the SDWebImage library and animates a set of images that load from an array of ImageURLs into an ImageView component. It all works fine.

```
            imageView.animationDuration = 40.0;
            [imageView sd_setAnimationImagesWithURLs:animationImagesURLs];
```

But, I want to capture the transition from one image to another, so that I can change the text of a label on the same screen. I tried few delegate methods that SDWebImage has but none seem to catch the transition instant.

What is the actual delegate that gets called at the moment when the new image appears on the ImageView?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the implementation, you'd see that `SDWebImage` is not actually animating the image transitions. `UIImageView` has its own animation capabilities, and that is what `SDWebImage` uses. So there is no delegate method to be called.